# Using "attr" vs. "animate" to change Raphael object using node ID

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm building an application that uses Raphael to draw circles on a map based on values read from a json feed. Each circle node gets an ID, which I then use to call it and change its attributes. Selecting a new variable changes the size and color of the circles. I can change the size using JQuery's attr method, but not animate.

I've assigned an ID to each circle:

```
circle.raphael.node.id = [thisCircle]
```

I can change the size and color of each circle using the attribute method, thusly:

```
$(thisCircle).attr({
r : [new radius]
fill : [new color]
});
```

But I can't animate it using JQuery's animate method:

```
$(thisCircle).animate({
r : [new radius],
fill : [new color]
}, 200);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what are things between squared brackets? is this real code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why aren't you animating the raphael object through it's own [`animate`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate) method? :

```
circle.animate({
    r : newRadius,
    fill : newColor
},200);
```

Here's a demo that shows how to animate a raphael circle object :

#### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/MpjGJ/

.
In that same demo you'll see that I've added an unnecessary mini jquery plugin that lets you animate the raphael svg object through the native jquery animation method just like this :

```
$('#the-id-of-the-svg-node').animate({
    r : newRadius,
    fill : newColor
},200);
```

Comment: This is where I'm getting confused. Raphael has its own animate method, but I don't understand how to use it on an individual circle by calling its node id.

Comment: when you're accessing the node via jquery, yo do not have access to the raphael api, you only have access to the svg node that raphael generated.

Comment: This helped!! I ended up attaching the raphael svg node to my data so that when I looped through, I could animate the change with the raphael animate method, rather than the id using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

try and use `$('#'+thisCircle).animate...`. `[thisCircle]` is the underlying element's `id`, in order to pass it to jQuery you must specify a *selector* to select the element itself.